# How to delete collectionview records if encountered error 405?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, delete-row

I have a collection view and I would like to delete 1 of the records in the list. I use the code below when I click on a delete button:

```
NSString *wishlistID = @"5";
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://api.samplewebsite.com/api/product/wishlist_delete/%@",wishlistID];
[self.manager DELETE:url_string parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

[self.collectionView reloadData];
}
failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please try again"
                                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                     handler:nil];

    [alertVC addAction:okAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

I hit the error as below:

> Request failed: Method not allowed (405).

P.S.: Tested and able to delete records by using POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by using codes as below in server end > web.config:-

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" /> 
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You get [HTTP error code 405](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), which means that your server does not allow your request.

So it seems that your server does not allow you to DELETE the `http://api.samplewebsite.com/api/product/wishlist_delete/5` resource.

The error has nothing to do with your collection view, and neither with AFNetworking (which just passes on the DELETE request and its reply); I suggest you change the title.